# install4j project report generates empty html file

Tags: install4j

I'm reviewing install4j (9.0.7, windows 10) and have created a simple java installer with some additional screens to enter custom variables that we use to configure our product.

The installer that is generated seems to work ok.

Because it is recommended for search purposes (to see were for example you are using custom variables) to generate a "project report" I tried this and to my surprise it generates an empty html file of 0kb in size.

Is this a "bug" or did I miss something that I should have done before generating the project report.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression that can happen in 9.0.7, it will be fixed in the next bugfix release. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.